# Is there a Field/Widget for dexterity that does the same as Products.UserField does for Archetypes?

Tags: plone, dexterity

I'd like to create a dexterity type that has a user Field.

I have used [Products.UserField](http://plone.org/products/userfield) before but I'd like the new type to be a dexterity type.

Is there any equivalent for Products.UserField?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, I don't believe there is. Variety of supporting widgets is probably the single area in which Archetypes is still stronger than Dexterity.

It would probably not be difficult for a programmer familiar with z3c.forms to port the functionality. But, somebody will need to want it enough to make it happen — either by developing it themselves or by hiring a developer / offering a bounty.